# Jenkins. How to stop run tests during every second build?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, application-settings, jenkins-job-builder

How to make Jenkins run tests only during every second build?

Comment: How to do it using only the _Jenkins Environment Variables_ `build_number`?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the Conditional Build Plugin? (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin)

I think it can do what you're looking for.

There is a Boolean condition:

> Run the step if a token expands to a representation of true (or the string "run")

So you could use as condition if the Buildnumber modulo 2 is 0.